# Passing list elements to a for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to pass elements from a list to a for loop and of course am getting the classic error 'argument 1 must be a string not list' - for the os.chdir() function.

Here is a my code, any suggestions as to how I can get around the above error and still pass the elements of my list on to the rest of the script so it loops through each one would be greatly appreciated!!

```
path= ['C:\\DataDownload\Administrative', 'C:\\DataDownload\Cadastral', 'C:\\DataDownload\Development']
for x in path[:]:
   os.chdir(path)
   #Remove all previous files from the current folder
   for file in os.listdir(path):
     basename=os.path.basename(file)
     if basename.endswith('.DXF'):
        os.remove(file)
     if basename.endswith('.dbf'):
        os.remove(file)
     if basename.endswith('.kmz'):
        os.remove(file)
     if basename.endswith('.prj'):
        os.remove(file)
     if basename.endswith('.sbn'):
        os.remove(file)
     if basename.endswith('.sbx'):
        os.remove(file)
     if basename.endswith('.shp'):
        os.remove(file)
     if basename.endswith('.shx'):
        os.remove(file)  
     if basename.endswith('.zip'):
        os.remove(file)
     if basename.endswith('.xml'):
        os.remove(file)
```

Comment: Completely unrelated to your question, it would make your life far easier if you used an array of extensions: `extentions = ['.DXF', '.dbf', '.kmz', ..., '.xml']`. Then you can do something like `if any(map(lambda ext: basename.endswith(ext), extensions)): os.remove(file)`, or just `for ext in extensions: if basename.endswith(ext): os.remove(file); break`

Comment: Thanks Michael - I've incorporated your idea "for ext in extensions" into my code - much more efficient - a great learning for me!!

Comment: @Michael: `endswith` supports tuple as input, therefore you example could be simplified: `if basename.endswith(exts): os.remove(fname)`, given that `exts` is a tuple of extensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `os.chdir(x)` instead of `os.chdir(path)`.

`path` is the list containing all the paths (and should thus probably be named `paths`), so you can't use it as an argument to `chdir`.

Comment: You may also want to read up on for loops http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements and http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/fileinfo_for.html

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **double** your *backslashes* if you want to hardcode the Windows paths this way (otherwise you'll have unexpected behaviour pop up once you have a `\t` in your path for example).

No need for copying the list (with `path[:]`): `for x in path` will do just as well.

No need for explicitely calling `os.chdir`...

And the `if` clauses are a bit ugly (and hard to maintain); the example can thus be simplified like this:

```
directories = ['C:\\DataDownload\\Administrative', 
               'C:\\DataDownload\\Cadastral', 
               'C:\\DataDownload\\Development']

for directory in directories:
   for filename in os.listdir(directory):
     base_filename, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
     if extension in ['.DXF','.dbf','.kmz','.prj','.sbn','.sbx',
                      '.shp','.shx','.zip','.xml']:
        os.remove(os.path.join(directory, filename))
```

It might be helpful to look at the  [os module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html).

Comment: Alternatively use raw strings:  `r'C:\DataDownload\Administrative'`